# Vagrant Up: Error, VBoxMessage.exe : Error

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

This is the error i get once i type vagrant up to my homestead directory.

[image: This is the error i get once i type vagrant up to my homestead directory.]

Comment: this sounds like it belongs on [sf]

Comment: this is a known bug and this is must be fixed, why down vote?

Answer (score 0):

What version of vagrant? There is a known bug in (at least) vagrant 1.6.4 that causes the vbox hostonly adapter to fail. When I encountered it, 1.6.5 wasn't out yet (and I don't know if it fixed it), but downgrading to 1.6.3 solved it for me.

Edit: on second thought, this looks like a permissions issue. Virtual box needs to have elevated privileges (sudo/root) on the host machine to create network interfaces. If you don't have the appropriate access, try using the `virtualbox__intnet` flag on the `config.vm.network "private_network"` call

Comment: i thought the problem is the virtualbox itself, i'll let you know if this will solve my problem.